# Creating an R dataframe row-by-row

Tags: list, r, dataframe

I would like to construct a dataframe row-by-row in R. I've done some searching, and all I came up with is the suggestion to create an empty list, keep a list index scalar, then each time add to the list a single-row dataframe and advance the list index by one. Finally, `do.call(rbind,)` on the list.

While this works, it seems very cumbersome. Isn't there an easier way for achieving the same goal?

Obviously I refer to cases where I can't use some `apply` function and explicitly need to create the dataframe row by row. At least, is there a way to `push` into the end of a list instead of explicitly keeping track of the last index used?

Comment: You can use `append()` [which should probably be named insert] or `c()` to add items to the end of a list, though won't help you here.

Comment: There are not many functions in R that return data frames unless you return them [row-wise] from `lapply()`, `Map()`, and so on, but you may also want to take a look at `aggregate()`, `dapply() {heR.Misc}`, and `cast() {reshape}` to see if your tasks cannot be handled by these functions (these all return data frames).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can grow them row by row by appending or using `rbind()`.

That does not mean you should.  Dynamically growing structures is one of the least efficient ways to code in R.

If you can, allocate your entire data.frame up front:

```
N <- 1e4  # total number of rows to preallocate--possibly an overestimate

DF <- data.frame(num=rep(NA, N), txt=rep("", N),  # as many cols as you need
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)          # you don't know levels yet
```

and then during your operations insert row at a time

```
DF[i, ] <- list(1.4, "foo")
```

That should work for arbitrary data.frame and be much more efficient.  If you overshot N you can always shrink empty rows out at the end.

Comment: Didn't you mean to put N instead of 10, and list(1.4,"foo") instead of c(1.4,"foo") so as not to coerce the 1.4 into character mode?

Comment: Yes, I meant to use N in the data.frame creation. Also, very good catch re the coercion into chat -- I had missed that.

Comment: It'd be better to edit the answer than leave it in the comments.  I was confused trying to grok this answer.

Comment: `data.table` seems to be even faster than pre-allocation using data.frames.  Testing here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11486400/636656

Comment: is this still true in R 3.1 where this should be faster?

Answer (score 53):

One can add rows to `NULL`:

```
df<-NULL;
while(...){
  #Some code that generates new row
  rbind(df,row)->df
}
```

for instance

```
df<-NULL
for(e in 1:10) rbind(df,data.frame(x=e,square=e^2,even=factor(e%%2==0)))->df
print(df)
```

Comment: it outputs a matrix, not a data frame

Comment: @Olga Only if you bind rows of elements of an equal type -- BTW in that case it is better to `sapply` (or vectorise) and transpose.

Comment: @mbq Exactly what I'm doing. I also found that if you initialize it with df<-data.frame(), it outputs a data frame.

Answer (score 9):

This is a silly example of how to use `do.call(rbind,)` on the output of `Map()` [which is similar to `lapply()`]

```
> DF <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x) data.frame(a=x,b=x+1),x=1:3))
> DF
  x y
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
> class(DF)
[1] "data.frame"
```

I use this construct quite often.

Answer (score 8):

The reason I like Rcpp so much is that I don't always get how R Core thinks, and with Rcpp, more often than not, I don't have to.

Speaking philosophically, you're in a state of sin with regards to the functional paradigm, which tries to ensure that every value *appears* independent of every other value; changing one value should never cause a visible change in another value, the way you get with pointers sharing representation in C.

The problems arise when functional programming signals the small craft to move out of the way, and the small craft replies "I'm a lighthouse".  Making a long series of small changes to a large object which you want to process on in the meantime puts you square into lighthouse territory.

In the C++ STL, `push_back()` is a way of life.  It doesn't try to be functional, but it does try to accommodate common programming idioms *efficiently*.

With some cleverness behind the scenes, you can sometimes arrange to have one foot in each world.  Snapshot based file systems are a good example (which evolved from concepts such as union mounts, which also ply both sides).

If R Core wanted to do this, underlying vector storage could function like a union mount.  One reference to the vector storage might be valid for subscripts `1:N`, while another reference to the same storage is valid for subscripts `1:(N+1)`.  There could be reserved storage not yet validly referenced by anything but convenient for a quick `push_back()`.  You don't violate the functional concept when appending outside the range that any existing reference considers valid.

Eventually appending rows incrementally, you run out of reserved storage.  You'll need to create new copies of everything, with the storage multiplied by some increment.  The STL implementations I've use tend to multiply storage by 2 when extending allocation.  I thought I read in R Internals that there is a memory structure where the storage increments by 20%.  Either way, growth operations occur with logarithmic frequency relative to the total number of elements appended.  On an amortized basis, this is usually acceptable.

As tricks behind the scenes go, I've seen worse.  Every time you `push_back()` a new row onto the dataframe, a top level index structure would need to be copied.  The new row could append onto shared representation without impacting any old functional values.  I don't even think it would complicate the garbage collector much; since I'm not proposing `push_front()` all references are prefix references to the front of the allocated vector storage.

Answer (score 2):

Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer is the best; here I just note that you can get away with not pre-specifying the dataframe dimensions or data types, which is sometimes useful if you have multiple data types and lots of columns:

```
row1<-list("a",1,FALSE) #use 'list', not 'c' or 'cbind'!
row2<-list("b",2,TRUE)  

df<-data.frame(row1,stringsAsFactors = F) #first row
df<-rbind(df,row2) #now this works as you'd expect.
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found this way to create dataframe by raw without matrix.

With automatic column name

```
df<-data.frame(
        t(data.frame(c(1,"a",100),c(2,"b",200),c(3,"c",300)))
        ,row.names = NULL,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
```

With column name

```
df<-setNames(
        data.frame(
            t(data.frame(c(1,"a",100),c(2,"b",200),c(3,"c",300)))
            ,row.names = NULL,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        ), 
        c("col1","col2","col3")
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have vectors destined to become rows, concatenate them using `c()`, pass them to a matrix row-by-row, and convert that matrix to a dataframe.

For example, rows

```
dummydata1=c(2002,10,1,12.00,101,426340.0,4411238.0,3598.0,0.92,57.77,4.80,238.29,-9.9)
dummydata2=c(2002,10,2,12.00,101,426340.0,4411238.0,3598.0,-3.02,78.77,-9999.00,-99.0,-9.9)
dummydata3=c(2002,10,8,12.00,101,426340.0,4411238.0,3598.0,-5.02,88.77,-9999.00,-99.0,-9.9)
```

can be converted to a data frame thus:

```
dummyset=c(dummydata1,dummydata2,dummydata3)
col.len=length(dummydata1)
dummytable=data.frame(matrix(data=dummyset,ncol=col.len,byrow=TRUE))
```

Admittedly, I see 2 major limitations: (1) this only works with single-mode data, and (2) you must know your final # columns for this to work (i.e., I'm assuming that you're not working with a ragged array whose greatest row length is unknown *a priori*).

This solution seems simple, but from my experience with type conversions in R, I'm sure it creates new challenges down-the-line. Can anyone comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of your new row, you might use `tibble::add_row` if your new row is simple and can specified in "value-pairs". Or you could use `dplyr::bind_rows`, "an efficient implementation of the common pattern of do.call(rbind, dfs)".