# Growing a data.frame in a memory-efficient manner

Tags: r, memory, dataframe

According to [Creating an R dataframe row-by-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642535/creating-an-r-dataframe-row-by-row), it's not ideal to append to a `data.frame` using `rbind`, as it creates a copy of the whole data.frame each time. How do I accumulate data in `R` resulting in a `data.frame` without incurring this penalty? The intermediate format doesn't need to be a `data.frame`.

Comment: Edited to make clear what I'm pretty sure you meant.  Please revert if I messed up.

Comment: If you are still interested, [here is another benchmark of other set of different way to grow data.frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689650/how-to-append-rows-to-an-r-data-frame/38052208#38052208) when you don't know the size in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**First approach**

I tried accessing each element of a pre-allocated data.frame:

```
res <- data.frame(x=rep(NA,1000), y=rep(NA,1000))
tracemem(res)
for(i in 1:1000) {
  res[i,"x"] <- runif(1)
  res[i,"y"] <- rnorm(1)
}
```

But tracemem goes crazy (e.g. the data.frame is being copied to a new address each time).

**Alternative approach (doesn't work either)**

One approach (not sure it's faster as I haven't benchmarked yet) is to create a list of data.frames, then `stack` them all together:

```
makeRow <- function() data.frame(x=runif(1),y=rnorm(1))
res <- replicate(1000, makeRow(), simplify=FALSE ) # returns a list of data.frames
library(taRifx)
res.df <- stack(res)
```

Unfortunately in creating the list I think you will be hard-pressed to pre-allocate.  For instance:

```
> tracemem(res)
[1] "<0x79b98b0>"
> res[[2]] <- data.frame()
tracemem[0x79b98b0 -> 0x71da500]:
```

In other words, replacing an element of the list causes the list to be copied.  I assume the whole list, but it's possible it's only that element of the list.  I'm not intimately familiar with the details of R's memory management.

**Probably the best approach**

As with many speed or memory-limited processes these days, the best approach may well be to use `data.table` instead of a `data.frame`.  Since `data.table` has the `:=` assign by reference operator, it can update without re-copying:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=rep(0,1000), y=rep(0,1000))
tracemem(dt)
for(i in 1:1000) {
  dt[i,x := runif(1)]
  dt[i,y := rnorm(1)]
}
# note no message from tracemem
```

But as @MatthewDowle points out, `set()` is the appropriate way to do this inside a loop.  Doing so makes it faster still:

```
library(data.table)
n <- 10^6
dt <- data.table(x=rep(0,n), y=rep(0,n))

dt.colon <- function(dt) {
  for(i in 1:n) {
    dt[i,x := runif(1)]
    dt[i,y := rnorm(1)]
  }
}

dt.set <- function(dt) {
  for(i in 1:n) {
    set(dt,i,1L, runif(1) )
    set(dt,i,2L, rnorm(1) )
  }
}

library(microbenchmark)
m <- microbenchmark(dt.colon(dt), dt.set(dt),times=2)
```

(Results shown below)

**Benchmarking**

With the loop run 10,000 times, data table is almost a full order of magnitude faster:

```
Unit: seconds
          expr        min         lq     median         uq        max
1    test.df()  523.49057  523.49057  524.52408  525.55759  525.55759
2    test.dt()   62.06398   62.06398   62.98622   63.90845   63.90845
3 test.stack() 1196.30135 1196.30135 1258.79879 1321.29622 1321.29622
```

[image: benchmarks]

And comparison of `:=` with `set()`:

```
> m
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq    median       uq      max
1 dt.colon(dt) 654.54996 654.54996 656.43429 658.3186 658.3186
2   dt.set(dt)  13.29612  13.29612  15.02891  16.7617  16.7617
```

Note that `n` here is 10^6 not 10^5 as in the benchmarks plotted above.  So there's an order of magnitude more work, and the result is measured in milliseconds not seconds.  Impressive indeed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your last example doesn't grow the data.table. You simply overwrite the first row 1,000 times.

Comment: That's good but have you seen the speed example at the bottom of `?":="` comparing `:=` within a loop to `set()` within a loop. `:=` has overhead (e.g. checking the existence and type of arguments passed to `[.data.table`), which is why `set()` is provided for use inside loops.

Comment: And overhead would explain why it wasn't the fastest on small data. Change to `set()` and it should be the fastest again.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Neat tip, thanks.  I couldn't find anything about `set()` documented in `?":="`, though, and even `?set` has only a comment that it "should be documented in ?":=", perhaps."

Comment: Ah yes, `set` is now (recently) better documented and lives in `?":="`. It's thanks to discussions with @JoshuaUlrich here on S.O. that `set()` got added to `data.table`. Search NEWS for string "set(" for further info.

Comment: Hm.  I'm running 1.8.0 on R1.15.0.  Time to upgrade maybe :-)

Comment: @Ari v1.8.2 is now on CRAN (last night) passing checks and working its way through the CRAN system.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Noted.  I'll take a look.

Answer (score 9):

You could also have an empty list object where elements are filled with dataframes; then collect the results at the end with sapply or similar.
An example can be found [here](http://menugget.blogspot.de/2011/11/another-aspect-of-speeding-up-loops-in.html). This will not incur the penalties of growing an object.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I am very surprised that nobody mentioned the conversion to a matrix yet...

Comparing with the **dt.colon** and **dt.set** functions defined by [Ari B. Friedman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486369/growing-a-data-frame-in-a-memory-efficient-manner/11486400#11486400) , the conversion to a matrix has the best running time (slightly quicker than **dt.colon**). All affectations inside a matrix are done by reference, so there is no unnecessary memory copy performed in this code.

CODE:

```
library(data.table)
n <- 10^4
dt <- data.table(x=rep(0,n), y=rep(0,n))

use.matrix <- function(dt) {
  mat = as.matrix(dt)  # converting to matrix
  for(i in 1:n) {
    mat[i,1] = runif(1)
    mat[i,2] = rnorm(1)
  }
  return(as.data.frame(mat))  # converting back to a data.frame
}


dt.colon <- function(dt) { # same as Ari's function
  for(i in 1:n) {
    dt[i,x := runif(1)]
    dt[i,y := rnorm(1)]
  }
}

dt.set <- function(dt) { # same as Ari's function
  for(i in 1:n) {
    set(dt,i,1L, runif(1) )
    set(dt,i,2L, rnorm(1) )
  }
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(dt.colon(dt), dt.set(dt), use.matrix(dt),times=10)
```

RESULT:

```
Unit: milliseconds
           expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
   dt.colon(dt) 7107.68494 7193.54792 7262.76720 7277.24841 7472.41726    10
     dt.set(dt)   93.25954   94.10291   95.07181   97.09725   99.18583    10
 use.matrix(dt)   48.15595   51.71100   52.39375   54.59252   55.04192    10
```

Pros of using a matrix:

- this is the fastest method so far
- you don't have to learn/use data.table objects

Con of using a matrix:

- you can only handle one data type in a matrix (in particular, if you had mixed types in the columns of your data.frame, then they will all be converted to *character* by the line: **mat = as.matrix(dt)  # converting to matrix**)

Answer (score 6):

I like `RSQLite` for that matter: `dbWriteTable(...,append=TRUE)` statements while collecting, and `dbReadTable` statement at the end.

If the data is small enough, one can use the ":memory:" file, if it is big, the hard disk.

Of course, it can not compete in terms of speed:

```
makeRow <- function() data.frame(x=runif(1),y=rnorm(1))

library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

collect1 <- function(n) {
  for (i in 1:n) dbWriteTable(con, "test", makeRow(), append=TRUE)
  dbReadTable(con, "test", row.names=NULL)
}

collect2 <- function(n) {
  res <- data.frame(x=rep(NA, n), y=rep(NA, n))
  for(i in 1:n) res[i,] <- makeRow()[1,]
  res
}

> system.time(collect1(1000))
   User      System verstrichen 
   7.01        0.00        7.05  
> system.time(collect2(1000))
   User      System verstrichen 
   0.80        0.01        0.81
```

But it might look better if the `data.frame`s have more than one row. And you do not need to know the number of rows in advance.

Comment: The idea is cool, but it [is far from efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689650/how-to-append-rows-to-an-r-data-frame/38052208#38052208). I put it on a test on another thread.

Answer (score 3):

[This post](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/) suggests stripping off `data.frame` / `tibble`'s class attributes using `as.list`, assigning list elements in-place the usual way and then converting the result back to `data.frame` / `tibble` again.  The computational complexity of this method grows linearly but with a very little rate of less than 10e-6.

```
in_place_list_bm <- function(n) {
    res <- tibble(x = rep(NA_real_, n))
    tracemem(res)
    res <- as.list(res)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        res[['x']][[i]] <- i
    }
    return(res %>% as_tibble())
}

> system.time(in_place_list_bm(10000))[[3]]
tracemem[0xd87aa08 -> 0xd87aaf8]: as.list.data.frame as.list in_place_list_bm system.time 
tracemem[0xd87aaf8 -> 0xd87abb8]: in_place_list_bm system.time 
tracemem[0xd87abb8 -> 0xe045928]: check_tibble list_to_tibble as_tibble.list as_tibble <Anonymous> withVisible freduce _fseq eval eval withVisible %>% in_place_list_bm system.time 
tracemem[0xe045928 -> 0xe043488]: new_tibble list_to_tibble as_tibble.list as_tibble <Anonymous> withVisible freduce _fseq eval eval withVisible %>% in_place_list_bm system.time 
tracemem[0xe043488 -> 0xe043728]: set_tibble_class new_tibble list_to_tibble as_tibble.list as_tibble <Anonymous> withVisible freduce _fseq eval eval withVisible %>% in_place_list_bm system.time 
[1] 0.006
> system.time(in_place_list_bm(100000))[[3]]
tracemem[0xdf89f78 -> 0xdf891b8]: as.list.data.frame as.list in_place_list_bm system.time 
tracemem[0xdf891b8 -> 0xdf89278]: in_place_list_bm system.time 
tracemem[0xdf89278 -> 0x5e00fb8]: check_tibble list_to_tibble as_tibble.list as_tibble <Anonymous> withVisible freduce _fseq eval eval withVisible %>% in_place_list_bm system.time 
tracemem[0x5e00fb8 -> 0x5dd46b8]: new_tibble list_to_tibble as_tibble.list as_tibble <Anonymous> withVisible freduce _fseq eval eval withVisible %>% in_place_list_bm system.time 
tracemem[0x5dd46b8 -> 0x5dcec98]: set_tibble_class new_tibble list_to_tibble as_tibble.list as_tibble <Anonymous> withVisible freduce _fseq eval eval withVisible %>% in_place_list_bm system.time 
[1] 0.045
```

Here is an image from the original article:
[image]