# building nested lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops, nested

I have written a function that it's output is a list. I want to put my function into a loop and I'd like to store output of each iteration (which is of course a list) into a bigger list. In other words, each element of this BIG list is also a list. c() does not do what I want. Is there any way to do that?

To understand better what I'm asking, consider the example below:

```
iter1 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "a")
iter2 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "b")
All <- list(iter1 = iter1, iter2 = iter2)
```

I want to be able to do something similar to the code above but in a loop. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: I think you want to say "nesting" instead of "concatenating" in the title...and maybe mention the loop thing?

Comment: you want c, you just need an extra call to `list`:  `c(LL, list(l1))`

Comment: Don't grow objects in loops!! Preallocate and then fill.

Comment: This is not concatenation, I've fixed title and tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's another way to assign to a list, using `my_list[[name or number]] <-`. If you really want to do that in a loop, just looping over things with names like iter1, iter2, ...

```
A <- list()
n_iter <- 2
for (i in 1:n_iter){
    iname <- paste("iter",i,sep="")
    A[[iname]] <- get(iname)
}
```

As @mnel pointed out, dynamically growing a list is inefficient. The alternative is, I think, to use `lapply`:

```
n_iter <- 2
inames <- paste("iter",1:n_iter,sep="")
names(inames) <- inames
A <- lapply(inames,get)
```

This can also be done with a data frame, which would be a better format if your sublists always have two elements, each having a consistent class (item1 being numeric and item 2 being character).

```
n_iter <- 2
DF <- data.frame(item1=rep(0,n_iter),item2=rep("",n_iter),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
for (i in 1:n_iter){
     iname <- paste("iter",i,sep="")
     DF[i,] <- get(iname)
     rownames(DF)[i] <- iname
}

#       item1 item2
# iter1     1     a
# iter2     1     b
```

However, that's a pretty ugly way of doing things; things get messy pretty quickly when using `get`. With your data structure, maybe you want to create iter1 and iter2 in a loop and immediately embed them into the parent list or data frame?

```
n_iter = 10
DF <- data.frame(item1 = rep(0,n_iter), item2 = rep("",n_iter))
for (i in 1:n_iter){
    ... do stuff to make anum and achar ...
    DF[i,"item1"] <- anum
    DF[i,"item2"] <- achar
}
```

Where anum and achar are the values of item1 and item2 you want to store from that iteration. [Elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486369/growing-a-data-frame-in-a-memory-efficient-manner/11486400#11486400), they say that there is an alternative using the `data.table` package that is almost 10x as fast/efficient as this sort of data-frame assignment.

Oh, one last idea: if you want to put them in a list first, you can easily convert to a data frame later with

```
DF <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,A)
```

Comment: @SimonO101 . Thanks for pointing out the issue with my first example. :) Please let me know if there's a problem with the edited version.

Comment: + 1 for your comprehensive treatment of the alternatives

Answer (score 5):

This gets you the equivalent of your `All`

```
c(iter1=list(iter1), iter2=list(iter2))

> identical(c(iter1=list(iter1), iter2=list(iter2)), All)
[1] TRUE
```

Let's say you'd like to add a third list to `All`:

```
c(All, list(iter3=iter3))
```

---

If you don't care for the list names, it looks a little cleaner

```
 c(list(iter1), list(iter2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Frank's answer is the correct one here, but the first example he gave seemed a little strange. I think you want to do this...

```
bigLL <- list()
for( i in 1:3 ){

  ll <- list( item1 = i , item2 = letters[i] )
  bigLL[[i]] <- ll

}

bigLL
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$item1
#[1] 1

#[[1]]$item2
#[1] "a"


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$item1
#[1] 2

#[[2]]$item2
#[1] "b"


#[[3]]
#[[3]]$item1
#[1] 3

#[[3]]$item2
#[1] "c"
```

but you should consider the alternatives by Frank if possible.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me very well, hope it helps.

```
  data = list()

  for(i in 1:3)
  {
    tmp = c(1,2,3)
    data = rbind(data, tmp)
  }
```

Comment: `rbind` is not for lists - it will ignore the fact that `data` starts as a list.  Also, continually calling `rbind` in a loop is slow as `data` must be re-evaluated at each step.  Try using `data[[i]] <- tmp` in each loop and then `do.call(rbind, data)` after the loop.