# Running loops and receiving an error message

Tags: r

```
c <- 3  # set the initial numbers
d <- acadfull[,c]
i <- 1
p <- 1
data <- data.frame()

while (i < 123 ) {     #loop

  ANS <- lm(caco ~ d, data=acadfull)

  data[p,1] <-  ANS$coefficients                             

  c <- c+1  
  i <- i+1
  p <- p+1
  d <- acadfull[,c]

  if (i==123)
    break

}

write.csv(c(snp,pos,data),"reg_results", row.names=F)
```

Any help would really be appreciated! When I run the above script, I get an error message saying

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, p, 1, value = c(1.48484848484849,      -0.0104895104895094,  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 1
```

I get the error when this line is run

```
 ANS <- lm(caco ~ d, data=acadfull)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't subset a data frame like that, as you are telling the dataframe to change places that don't exist:

```
x <- data.frame()
x[ ,1]<-c(1, 2, 3)
```

Will give you the same error.

You can fix this in a variety of ways.

The easiest (and most inefficient) is using rbind:

```
data <-  rbind(data, ANS$coefficients)
```

As long are you aren't running a lot of data, this will be fine.

For a discussion of faster and more efficient ways of doing this, read this previous question - [Growing a data.frame in a memory efficient manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486369/growing-a-data-frame-in-a-memory-efficient-manner)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify your code. You don't need the `d` and `p` variables. You can use `rbind` to add rows to your data frame and I adjusted the linear model.

As I don't know exactly what `acadfull` is, I couldn't test the code, but hopefully it will work.

```
c <- 3  # set the initial numbers
i <- 1

data <- data.frame()

while (i < 123 ) {     #loop

  ANS <- lm(acadfull$caco ~ acadfull[c])

  data <-  rbind(data, ANS$coefficients)

  c <- c+1  
  i <- i+1

  if (i==123)
    break    
}

write.csv(c(snp,pos,data),"reg_results", row.names=F)
```

You could even discard your `i` variable by changing your `if` statement:

```
if (c == 126)
  break
```