# Building a `data.frame` of undefined number of rows in R

Tags: r, performance, memory, memory-management, dataframe

I am relatively often confronted with the building of a `data.frame` in R without knowing before-hand the number of rows I will need.

**When the number of rows is known**

```
nbrows = 10^5
d = data.frame(
  A=vector("numeric",nbrows),
  B=vector("numeric",nbrows)
)
for (i in 1:nbrows)
{
  ####
  # Do Stuff
  ####
  d[i,] = newline
}
```

**When the number of rows is unknown: Method 1**

Here is what I usually do

```
d = data.frame(
  A=numeric(),
  B=numeric()
)

while (TRUE)
{
  ###
  # Do Stuff
  ###
  d = rbind(d, newlines) # Note that several lines might be added
  if (condition) break
}
```

However, I suppose `rbind` is time costly as new memory is allocated at every iteration

**When the number of rows is unknown: Method 2**

It would be handy to allocate (without initializing values, if possible) some memory before-hand and just increase this memory every time we overpass the previously allocated memory.

I suppose the following would be relatively efficient in comparison to *Method 1*

```
expected_nbrows = 10^5
d = data.frame(
  A=vector("numeric",expected_nbrows),
  B=vector("numeric",expected_nbrows)
)
i = 1
while (TRUE)
{
  ####
  # Do Stuff
  ####
  nblines = nrow(newlines)
  if (i + nblines > nrow(d)) # if more memory is needed, then double the memory allocated to `d`
  {
    d = rbind(
      d,
      data.frame(
        A=vector("numeric",nrow(d)),
        B=vector("numeric",nrow(d))
      )
    )
  }
  d[i:(i+nblines),] = newlines
  i = i + nblines
  if (condition) break
}
```

**Question**

Is *Method 2* really more performant (in terms of CPU time) than *Method 1*?

Is there yet another better method?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486369/growing-a-data-frame-in-a-memory-efficient-manner

Comment: I suppose, but the specific methods you suggest aren't compared there. So yes, use data table if you want the fastest way. But I'm more curious about your existing question, because I was pretty sure I'd read somewhere that just assigning to the rows you want, without explicitly creating first (which does work) does the doubling thing behind the scenes. Haven't found any references about that yet, but if I'm still curious, I guess I'll have to write my own question.

Comment: @Aaron, or maybe Remi.b could benchmark his/her methods against those in the other question and add them as an answer there.  Would that satisfy your curiosity, or is it more that bechmarking that you're after?

Comment: I'm rereading those answers now and they all seem to assume preallocation is possible and focus on methods for accessing and replacing elements, instead of growing the output to an undetermined size. Am I missing something?

Comment: FWIW, just assigning to the rows doesn't double as it goes.