# Looping over a dataframe and it to a new dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to create an empty dataframe and therefore perform a loop and add the new content to a (new) dataframe.

Therefore I wrote something like this:

```
number <- c(1,2)
text <- c("Yes", "No")
df_test <- data.frame(number, text)

df_base = data.frame(number = numeric(), text = character())

for(i in 1:nrow(df_test)){

 text <- df_test$text[i]
 number <- df_test$number[i]

 df_temp <- data.frame(text, number)
 df_base <- rbind(df_base, df_temp) 

}
```

Code above does the trick but does not seem to be the most efficient way. Any thoughts on how I can write this better?

Comment: You should never create a data frame row by row in R ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642535/creating-an-r-dataframe-row-by-row)). In this case, why not just do `df_base <- df_test`?

Comment: This is just an example case....Just for reproduction purposes

Comment: If your goal is to change text or number columns in the new table, know that it's also usually more efficient to find a [vectorized](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html) solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the final size of your data.frame (df_base), you could pre-allocate the object:

```
df_base <- data.frame(text=character(nrow(df_test)),
                      number=numeric(nrow(dr_test)))
```

Then, in the loop, fill in these columns:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_test)){

  text <- df_test$text[i]
  number <- df_test$number[i]

  df_base[i,"text"] <- text
  df_base[i,"number"] <- number

}
```

This will save R from making multiple copies of df_base as it `rbind`s in each loop.

Comment: @Imo, sweet this helps. Thanks!